# Fibonacci em JS com arrays

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tentando fazer um código em JS que mostre o valor de fibonacci na posição escolhida usando vetores mas não sei por quê não estou conseguindo, alguém me ajuda no que estou errando? (O exercício que o prof passou é sobre vetores, sei que tem como fazer sem, mas preciso fazer com para treinar).

```js
function calcularFibonacci() {
    var i = 2;
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("numFibonacci").value, 10);
    var fib = new Array();
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    if(fib < 1)
        alert("Valores menores que 1 não são permitidos.");
    else{
        for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
        }
        alert("Posição = " + i + ".\nValor = " + n[i]);
    }
}
```

```css
legend{
 font-weight: bold;
}
input{
 text-align: center;
}
div#site{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
div#fibonacci{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
div#vetor{
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}
input#numFibonacci{
 width: 60px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input[name="inputVetor"]{
 width: 45px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
button{
 background-color: #999;;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: #666;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px 11px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
button[name="exibir"]{
 margin-top: 5px;
}
button:hover{
 background-color: #777; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Exercicio com Arrays</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="vetores.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fibonacci.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div id="site">
   <div id="fibonacci">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Sequência de Fibonacci</legend>
     Limite Fibonacci: <input type="number" id="numFibonacci" min="1" value="1"><br>
     <button id="buttonFibonacci" onClick="calcularFibonacci()">Exibir elemento na posição</button>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="vetor">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Vetor</legend>
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input0" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input1" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input2" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input3" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input4" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input5" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input6" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input7" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input8" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input9" value="0">
    </fieldset>
    <button name="exibir" onClick="calcularMaior()">Exibir MAIOR elemento</button>
    <button name="exibir" onClick="calcularMenor()">Exibir MENOR elemento</button><br>
    Último maior valor: <span id="lastMax"></span><br>
    Último menor valor: <span id="lastMin"></span><br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por que não posta o código aqui em vez do JSFiddle?

Comment: a parte importante do JS eu postei aqui, o resto é só se alguem quiser ver mesmo pra ajudar a entender, ia ficar muita coisa na tela aqui

Comment: Se você incrementar 1 no valor de `n` e ao imprimir o valor der um `fib[i - 1]` funciona. =)

Comment: valeu francisco, funcionou aqui =)

Comment: Viu como ficou mais fácil?! 

Answer (score 1):

O calculo dos números está correto mas a forma como os está a apresentar é que não:

```
alert("Posição = " + i + ".\nValor = " + n[i]);
```

Está a mostrar o `i` como posição, que quando o `for` termina já ficou um elemento à frente do `n` e por isso já não tem o valor que pretende. Para além disso está a aceder a `n` como se fosse um array, quando o seu array se chama `fib`.

Correto seria:

```
alert("Posição = " + n + ".\nValor = " + fib[n]);
//                   ^--                   ^---
```

Veja essa alteração em ação:

```js
function calcularFibonacci() {
    var i = 2;
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("numFibonacci").value, 10);
    var fib = new Array();
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    if(fib < 1)
        alert("Valores menores que 1 não são permitidos.");
    else{
        for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
        }
        alert("Posição = " + n + ".\nValor = " + fib[n]);
    }
}
```

```css
legend{
 font-weight: bold;
}
input{
 text-align: center;
}
div#site{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
div#fibonacci{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
div#vetor{
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}
input#numFibonacci{
 width: 60px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input[name="inputVetor"]{
 width: 45px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
button{
 background-color: #999;;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: #666;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px 11px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
button[name="exibir"]{
 margin-top: 5px;
}
button:hover{
 background-color: #777; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Exercicio com Arrays</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="vetores.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fibonacci.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div id="site">
   <div id="fibonacci">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Sequência de Fibonacci</legend>
     Limite Fibonacci: <input type="number" id="numFibonacci" min="1" value="1"><br>
     <button id="buttonFibonacci" onClick="calcularFibonacci()">Exibir elemento na posição</button>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="vetor">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Vetor</legend>
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input0" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input1" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input2" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input3" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input4" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input5" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input6" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input7" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input8" value="0">
     <input type="number" name="inputVetor" id="input9" value="0">
    </fieldset>
    <button name="exibir" onClick="calcularMaior()">Exibir MAIOR elemento</button>
    <button name="exibir" onClick="calcularMenor()">Exibir MENOR elemento</button><br>
    Último maior valor: <span id="lastMax"></span><br>
    Último menor valor: <span id="lastMin"></span><br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aproveito para relembrar que o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) irá normalmente interpretar em base `10` a menos que a `string` de entrada esteja formatada como hexadecimal (`0x...`) ou como octal (numero com zeros à esquerda). Por este motivo é muito comum de se utilizar o `parseInt` sem indicar a base (*radix*).

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, essa do parseInt eu nao sabia, mas acho que vou continuar indicando a base pra via das duvidas ^^